# How can I prevent the end of my animation from suddenly 'snapping' in?

Tags: html, css

I have an animation layout that I'm doing and the animation is so close to perfect, but at the final stage of the animation, you'll see that the top and bottom inner element 'snap' to a different size at the last second. I want the final container to have inner elements of 20%/60%/20% in height.

Is it possible to do this and remove that 'snapping' effect at the end?

```js
const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const three = document.querySelector('.three');


one.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  one.style.position = 'static';
}, true)

three.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  console.log('transition working');
  three.style.position = 'static';
}, true)
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  position: relative;
}
    
@keyframes right-up {
  0% {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  } 
}     
.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #FFAB7F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container:hover .one {
  animation: right-up 1s forwards;
}
/* .container:hover .two {
  height: 80%;
} */
.container:hover .three{
  height: 20%;
}
      
.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00529B;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.three {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #83FFA4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't manage to see the “snapping” effect you talk about. Or maybe that's my eyes!… =)

Comment: I've noticed the snapping effect but this appears to only occur on the first time you do the transition? Is this correct? The other times for me seem to have worked fine.

Comment: @slee423 That's correct, it only happens the first time, because once the JS changes the position to 'static', the issue appears no more!

Comment: @TakitIsy Please see the comments below yours!

Comment: I admit I must have missed it on the first execution. But now, I saw the effect! That's not my eyes… I'm so glad! :D ⋅⋅⋅ Why do you use static? Do you need it?

Comment: Nothing now about this? You didn't answer my comments.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is can make a bit change.

```js
const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const three = document.querySelector('.three');


one.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  one.style.position = 'static';
}, true)

three.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  console.log('transition working');
  three.style.position = 'static';
}, true)
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  position: relative;
}
    
@keyframes right-up {
  0% {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  } 
}     
.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #FFAB7F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container:hover .one {
  animation: right-up 1s forwards;
}
/* .container:hover .two {
  height: 80%;
} */
.container:hover .three{
  height: 20%;
}
      
.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00529B;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.three {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #83FFA4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. But thank you! The green element still has the snap effect and so does the top element still has a jagged snapping effect. :(

Answer (score 0):

I played a little with your code…  Tell me if this solution is correct for you:
(I commented the code instead of removing it)

```js
/*const one = document.querySelector('.one');
const three = document.querySelector('.three');

one.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
  one.style.position = 'static';
}, true)

three.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  console.log('transition working');
  three.style.position = 'static';
}, true)*/
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 425px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 5% auto;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes right-up {
  0% {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
  } 
}     
.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #FFAB7F;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container:hover .one {
  animation: right-up 1s forwards;
}

.container:hover .three{
  height: 20%;
}
      
.two {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #00529B;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.three {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #83FFA4;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all 1s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This was SO close but I do need that `.two` container as well.. :(

Comment: If there is a way you could get this to work with all 3 elements inside of the container, I would be forever grateful...I am thinking of adding a couple more elements to make this work now...I'll get back to you if I find a solution.

Comment: @WonkasWilly Now it works with the 3 elements but, well, the only thing I did is to comment all the js. Divs don't become static. Is that an issue ?